# How to use material Tree with only one object, not a List

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've made one component which uses mat-tree in a flat version where I show on screen a list of nested object. That I know how to do.

Right now I would like to make a simpler version of this component to present only one nested object, but when I try to put it into

```
this.dataSource.data = object
```

I got an error that data expects a list. What should I do if I only want to show one nested object on screen like

```
---Parent
------Child
--------Granchild
```

I'm using TreeDataModel:

```
    name: string;
    id: number;
    level: number;
    children: TreeDataModel[];
    style: string;
    expand: boolean
```

using the angular material library?

Comment: The only way I could do it was to convert the object to a list. Did you figure out any other way?

Comment: From what I recall I've change from flat angular tree to the other option

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving it an array with just your Object as the only item in it?

```js
this.dataSource.data = [object];
```

Comment: I've tried it now in ngOnInit of the simple component I can see that this.dataSource.data looks fine, but I got nothing in my html